# Loss not decreasing : all sigmoid values close to 0 during training after few iterations

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution, lstm

I am training a network for detecting sentence similarity (paraphrase detection) using joint loss from LSTM layer and CNN layer. The final cost is simply the summation of individual loss (likelihood loss) from these two layers.

Probability of two sentence to be similar: `sigmoid(vec1TWvec2 + b)`, where vec1 and vec2 are vector representations of the two sentences, W and b are weights and biases to be learnt during training.

Final loss = Loss from LSTM layer + Loss from CNN layer.

When I train the system on sample data of 32 random sentences, my model converges well.

> However, on using complete data the loss becomes stagnant and all
>   sigmoid values goes to very close to 0.

My network parameters:

- Gradient Descent Optimizer with learning rate 0.01 or 0.001.
- Hidden State Dim 200.
- Word Embedding Dim 300.
- Gradient Clipping by norm to 5.
- 1 Layer of convolution with 200 kernels followed by 1 layer of max pool.

Can anyone give my any hint on what might be the issue with training on complete data even though it works on small dataset? Is there a problem of vanishing gradient?